# My $.get request fails but the value I need is in the error message. How can I get it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, console.log

I make a get request, it fails, I look in console and what I needed is displayed right there. I know, it sounds strange but it's happening. If I can get that value, a workaround is possible.

What's my goal? I'm trying to resolve SoundCloud URLs which have a known problem of randomly deciding to throw a 403 when using their API.

**However, I noticed the value I need (track id) is displayed in the error!**

[image]

The red error text "GET https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1848538.json?client_id=17a992358db64d99e4923… 403 (Forbidden) has the value I need which is "1848538".

So the error gives me what I need and displays it in the console.

**How do I get it?**

Comment: How are you making the call to the API? What data are you providing in your ajax call to be sent as part of the request? Are you sure you don't already have access to the value in your own code?

Comment: Simple GET (shown in image) using jQuery $.get. No, I don't have access to the value or I wouldn't have posted the question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Say you make an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to a URL that returns an error, you can use the `error` property of ajax to retrieve the returned URL.

Then do a simple test using a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to retrieve the track ID.

The code assumes the URL returned is what you want.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1848538.json?client_id=17a992358db64d99e4923',
    context: this,
    success: this.mySuccess,
    error: this.myError,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.url = settings.url;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        var testUrl = jqXHR.url;
        // Do a match to retrieve the track id 
        var trackId = testUrl.match(new RegExp('/tracks/' + "(.*)" + '.json?'));
        alert(trackId[1]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, that looks sweet! Will do some further testing but I can't see why it won't work. Thank you!

Comment: It is perfect! Plus, I learned something from you that I may be able to use in the future or to help someone else with. You are the man. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Thanks and good luck with the rest of your code. :)

Comment: Love when a plan comes together. Just need to get rid of the quotes around the trackID (returns "1848538", need 1848538). I use the track_ID as in element in a URL which doesn't like the quotes.

Comment: The quotes are from a JSON.stringify I need for the successful URLs. My error, you returned precisely. All set!

Comment: Uh oh. var testURL works when the error is hardcoded. Can't determine what to switch to grab the actual error string from a failed GET. The GET errors are going to throw different URLs for each it can't resolve. Need to grab the URL generated by the current error.

Comment: `testUrl` was an assumption on the kind of URL the call is returning based on the use case you provided. In the code, you would change `testUrl` to `jqXHR.url` first which has the failed URL the ajax call is returning instead of the one hardcoded for the example to work.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Maybe the code example should be updated?

Comment: I'm lost. Don't know where to change testUrl to jqXHR.url

Comment: I've updated the snippet to change `testUrl` from the example use case to `jqXHR.url` that is returned from the ajax error object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156057/discussion-between-user1452893-and-kamran-khan).